# Pairwise independence and joint independence of events

Tags: probability, independence, combinatorics

I found the following problem in the book *[The Theory of Probability: Explorations and Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107024471)* by Santosh S. Venkatesh.

> Consider the sample space comprised of all $k!$ permutations of the
>   symbols $a_1,...,a_k$, together with the sequences of $k$ symbols
>   obtained by repeating a given symbol $k$ times. Assign to each
>   permutation the probability $\frac{1}{k^2(k-2)!}$ and each repetition
>   the probability $\frac{1}{k^2}$. Let $A_i$ be the event that the
>   symbol $a_i$ occurs in the $i-$th location. Determine if the events
>   $A_1,...,A_k$ are pairwise independent and whether they are jointly
>   independent.

My idea is:
$\Omega=\{a_1a_2...a_k,a_2a_1...a_k,...,a_1a_1...a_1,a_2a_2...a_2,...,a_ka_k...a_k\}$

Let's check pairwise independence between $A_i$ and $A_j$. W.l.o.g. $i=1$,$j=2$
$$P(A_1)=P(\{a_1a_2a_3...a_k,a_1a_3a_2...a_k,...,a_1a_1...a_1\})=(k-1)!\frac{1}{k^2(k-2)!}+\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{1}{k}$$
Similarly $P(A_2)=\frac{1}{k}$
Also $$P(A_1\cap A_2)=P(\{a_1a_2a_3a_4...a_k,a_1a_2a_4a_3...a_k,...\})=(k-2)!\frac{1}{k^2(k-2)!}=\frac{1}{k^2}$$
so that $P(A_1\cap A_2)=P(A_1)P(A_2)$ and we can see that this holds for every pair $(i,j)$. Thus $A_1,...,A_n$ are pairwise independent. Now let's take
$$P(A_1\cap A_2\cap...\cap A_k)=P(\{a_1a_2...a_k\})=\frac{1}{k^2(k-2)!}$$
$$P(A_i)=\frac{1}{k}$$ for $i=1,2,...,k$ as shown previously.
So 
$$P(A_1)P(A_2)...P(A_k)=\frac{1}{k^k}$$ which doesn't necessarily equal $P(A_1\cap A_2\cap...\cap A_k)$ so the events are not jointly independent in general. The above condition I checked wouldn't of course be enough for joint independence but it's necessary. Is this proof correct? Other ideas?

Comment: What might you be hoping for besides a simple "yes"?

Comment: @whuber potential flaws in the proof and possibly other approaches.